# md-select show already selected values

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

So I have the following:

```
<div layout-gt-sm="row">
    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
        <label>Documents</label>
        <md-select multiple ng-model="ctrl.data.documents" placeholder="Documents" ng-controller="DocumentsCtrl"> // I want to show the submitted values.
            <md-option ng-value="doc" ng-repeat="doc in allItems">{{ doc.name }}</md-option> // A list of other values
            <div ng-hide="allItems.length">No items found</div>
        </md-select>
    </md-input-container>
</div>
```

`ctrl.data.documents` is an array of already selected values.

What I am trying to achieve is to present this array (`ctrl.data.documents`)  in the field options and a list with the other values which is the `ng-repeat` in this case. The `ng-repeat` works just fine.  I am able to select other values. But can't figure out how to show the already selected values.

Did some digging I thought `ng-options` might do it, but can't seem to get it working (not supported ??) and `ng-selected` did not do the trick as well.

Any help or ideas?

**Update #1:**

Added a picture of the ctr.data.documents array.

[image]

Comment: update the post with **ctrl.data.documents** and **allItems** json data

Comment: also will be great if there is plunker created.

Comment: @Aravind update the post with a picture of the array. Never dealt with a plunker, will give it a try.

Comment: @user3641381 better add json format data, it's not helping. What value holding `allItems` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.id'}"` and `ng-repeat="doc in allItems track by doc.id"`. The `id` part should be your identifying marker of your document.

```
<md-select multiple ng-model="ctrl.data.documents"
    ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.id'}"
    placeholder="Documents" ng-controller="DocumentsCtrl"> 
    <md-option ng-value="doc" ng-repeat="doc in allItems track by doc.id">{{ doc.name }}</md-option>
    <div ng-hide="allItems.length">No items found</div>
</md-select>
```

Most of this is documented here: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSelect

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your time!